# Generate N unique random integers within a specified range

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, random

In an (1,80) dataframe containing zeros, I want to set N (=30) values to one at random positions, so I tried this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame( 0, index = range(1), columns = range(80) )
df[ np.random.randint(80, size=30) ] = 1
```

but then if I check, I get 25 "ones" instead of 30 :

```
( df.loc[0] == 1 ).sum()
25
```

What is wrong and how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the call to `np.random.randint` might return the same value twice and this redundancy is taken away by pandas (check `df[[1, 1]]`). So instead you can use `np.random.choice(80, 30, replace=False)`.

Answer (score 3):

The random integers generated need not be unique. Consequently, the same indices are getting set to 1 multiple times. I am sure you would get different sums everytime you run it.

You can use `random.sample(range(0,80), 30)` to generate 30 unique indices in the range.

[Doc](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/random.html#random.sample)